# MVC displaying collection: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Models.ConversionRate' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections

I have an object that I am successfully passing to my view with a collection inside that is properly populated.

My Model.
conversion_rates is simply a collection of doubles:

```
public class Converter
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public string documentation { get; set; }
    public string terms_of_use { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public string time_last_update { get; set; }
    public string time_next_update { get; set; }
    public ConversionRate conversion_rates { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller.
currencyConverter is properly passed through to my view:

```
public class Rates
{
    public static Converter Import()
    {
        try
        {
            string URLString = "https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/APIKey/latest/gbp";
            using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                var json = webClient.DownloadString(URLString);
                Converter Test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Converter>(json);
                return Test;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         ...
        }
    }
}


public IActionResult Index()
{
    var currencyConverter = Rates.Import();
    return View(currencyConverter);
}
```

My View:

```
@using System.Collections;
@model Converter

@foreach (var currency in (IEnumerable)Model.conversion_rates)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @currency
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that Model.conversion_rates is properly populated, but I can't get each individual element stored in my var currency for display in my table.

I can access each individual element and display them fine by just doing:

```
**@Successfully pulled data: @Model.conversion_rates.AED**
```

But for many reasons, this isn't practical. New values could be added dynamically etc. So I need to access the data in my Converter.conversion_rates, which is the collection I need to access.

This is an answer I came across, but it gives me the following error:

**InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Models.ConversionRate' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.**

The most notable, similar answer I could find suggests turning my returned model itself to an IEnumerable, but it doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because I'm only returning one object, and the actual collection I want to access is inside the Converter object itself, so turning Converter into a collection of 1 doesn't help. Also if I do this, I can't access Model.conversion_rates directly either.

```
@model IEnumerable<Converter>

@foreach (var currency in Model.conversion_rates)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @currency
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Edit: So an earlier fix I tried appears to be the correct one, my model is better off with:

```
public IEnumerable<ConversionRate> conversion_rates { get; set; }
```

But this messes up my json Deserialization. Will update if I find the fix.

Final code:

Comment: Can you post ConversionRate class pls?

Comment: hey again @serge, updated it in my post up top.

Comment: You've not shown your json string, but based on the error and Serge's answer you can likely change Conversion_Rates to a `Dictionary<string, double>`. That itself is then iterable and you don't have to use reflection like in his answer. I love reflection, you can do some pretty awesome things with it. But quite frankly it should be the absolute last thing you use. If a Dictionary won't work then write a custom converter--a basic task in json.net and "simple" with S.T.J. (you've not noted which you use and that's actually quite important). With all respect, I'd run from the accepted answer

Comment: Also if you use visual studio there's a very neat tool you can use. Copy your json data to your clipboard. In visual studio go to Edit->Paste Special->JSON as Classes. It will generate a full class hierarchy for your data. But like I said, if Serge's answer works for you then all you really need is to define the property as a `Dictionary<string, double>` instead of a `ConversionRate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your class

```
public class Converter
{
    ......
    public ConversionRate conversion_rates { get; set; }
    public  IEnumerable<ConversionRateItem> ConversionRateItems { get; set; }
}

public class ConversionRateItem
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public double Value {get; set;}
}
```

and action

```
 var currencyConverter = Rates.Import();

 var items = currencyConverter.conversion_rates.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Select(p => new ConversionRateItem
        {
         Name=p.Name,
        Value = (double) p.GetValue(currencyConverter .conversion_rates, null)
        }).ToArray();

  converter.ConversionRateItems=items;
converter.conversion_rates=null;

    return View(currencyConverter);
```

and finaly view

```
@foreach (var currency in Model.ConversionRateItems)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @currency.Name
    </td>
 <td>
        @currency.Value
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @serge, I did try this but it messes up the way my controller populates the object.

My Converter object is recieved like so:

`                    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
                    {
                        var json = webClient.DownloadString(URLString);
                        Converter Test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Converter>(json);`

And changing my class like that gives me an error requiring me to change my JSON to a JSON array, will that fix work?

Comment: @casperf1 You have to fix your controller code. You don't have any another choice.

Comment: @sarge really nice to have a fix, been at it for hours, thanks. So with the message I get:

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'conversion_rates.GBP', line 1, position 360.

Will changing to a JSON array be adequate?

Comment: If you have a big problem with the data you have to start from it. Post your json string and ask how to deserialize it. Only after this you can think about the view

Comment: Will do, appreciate the help again.

Comment: just wanted to give you a huge thanks, this was incredibly helpful and a great refresher. I've done a project similar to this before where I had to create a list to store an object that's a collection, and looking at your answer it makes complete sense. I was assuming just because ConversionRate was a collection, I'd be able to use it that way, but what you've done here is great clarification. Again, really appreciated, been at this for hours. I'm curious though, why do you list converter.conversion_rates as null in your example?

Comment: I just assumed that after converting to Items you don't need it any more.  Just to free some memory.

Comment: If this answer was helpfull for you, please don't forget to accept it othewise it will be down voted.

Comment: Accepted your answer, and that makes sense! Seems like good practice too. Thanks again @serge.

Comment: I wouldn't use reflection this way. I'd find a way to make your json deserialize to the format you want. If you're using json.net it's really simple to write a converter to turn a single item into a collection. But it also feels like you're using the wrong model types to begin with. You can likely replace it with a Dictionary<string, double> which then becomes iterable and you don't pay for the  cost or brittleness of reflection. Also assigning to null likely has zero noticable impact

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I am sorry but can you see any Json here? How do you know  then what is json file like and how can you deserialize it? Here we just  can see a class with a ton of properties and the task was to convert it to array.

Comment: No. But neither did you :p. However if your answer does in fact work without any errors, then **by definition** so would a `Dictionary<string, double>`. OP didn't ask for an array,  they asked for something they could iterate over. Reflection is not needed here.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  Thank you very much for your opinion. I really appreciate it. But I personally prefer a strongly typed array of classes instead of a generic dictionary.

Comment: @Serge Sure, me too if it wasn't just a key/value pair... By using reflection you are not only incurring a (negligible these days) perf hit, you're also by definition veering outside the realm of type safety. Sure you end up with something statically types, but you got it the hard way. "Paste JSON as Classes" would *likely* give the OP a strongly typed collection class instead, which would also work without reflection -- though only they can say for sure since we can't see his data and the url is behind a paywall

Comment: And don't get me wrong. I write some pretty complicated reflection-based code on a regular basis (IL emit, compiled expressions), just look at the first sentence of my profile. But its overkill here when there's surely simpler solutions that don't involve it. The only reason I've not written my own answer is because I'm not willing to do so without all the important details (the JSON example for starters). Hence I leave it to comments

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I personally hate reflections and always trying not to use them at all. Here i could see only 2 options: or I use each hard coded property and get 100 lines of code or using reflections.  I can only repeat again nor you nor me have not seen a json file and can't tell that it should be converted to a dictionary instead of the whole class. But I usually trust OP and believe that he could not convert json to  a dictionary because of json file structure.